# unsuported Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 (not realizing it was an old unsupported version). I lost access to windows 7 at boot up (it messed up the boot up drivers) have since downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.3 How do I install the latter version?

Answer (score 0):

Create a bootable usb drive of the Ubuntu 14.04.3 and install it on your system.

Use `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/iso/file.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

(Make sure you replace `sdb` with whatever node your usb drive is)

or use Startup Disk Creator to create the bootable USB flash drive.